# Making Bootstrap Model Show only Once per Visitor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using the following code to popup a bootstrap modal on my site. I want this model to display only once per visitor. I am thinking a cookie would do the trick, but I can't seem to get that to work for me. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome to Scotidi.com</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotform.com/jsform/53608453976972"></script>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Don't Sign Me Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see that you are setting a cookie anywhere.  Many times, cookies may be too heavy.  Have youthought of using localStorage?

Comment: I've never used localStorage. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Brian  thanks for the response... FYI, I took off the cookie code... it was:
`code`<script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function(){ if($.cookie('msg') != null && $.cookie('msg') != "") { $("div#myModal.modal, .modal-backdrop").hide(); } else { $('#myModal').modal('show'); $.cookie('msg', 'str'); } }); </script>`code`

Comment: You can use the localStorage global var in javascript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage